# Blender Units, wrong scale (but different scale) in every direction

Tags: units

I'll keep it short here, I have a model about 65x32x13mm ([Both .blend and .obj are here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sf8kfkCtA7YniP3uZT-hvJB_QZHKKeX1?usp=sharing)), I was going to attempt to print my model however any time I bring the model out of blender (Export as .STL/.OBJ) my dimensions go out the window and I can't solve it using scaling as the dimensions are scaled differently.  ATM my Y axis outside of blender scales by 228%, my X axis by 172% and my Z axis about 107%.

Is there any way to fix this?  If not, why does blender even give you the option to display measurements if they're completely proprietary to Blenders ecosystem.
Thanks, Rowan.

Comment: Sounds like it's related to non-uniform scale (caused by scaling in object mode). When you view the dimensions, are you in edit mode or object mode? Ideally, the dimensions should be 65x32x13 in edit mode, but the _scale_ in object mode (viewed in the tool menu accessed by pressing N) should be 1 for all axes. If it is not, (in object mode) select your object and press Ctrl+A (apply menu) and select "Scale".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not applied scale to your model.  If you look at it in object mode, you will see the scales to be:

[image: scales in object mode]

notice the inverse of those scales:  X 1/.437 = 2.28 = 228%, for example.

Select the object in object mode and type CTRL-A to bring up the apply menu.  Select "scale".  Once you've done that everything should export fine.

[image: Apply scale]

Comment: God bless you Marty, this is my first fore into Blender and I appreciate the concise and exactly correct solution.  Cheers!